# bluetooth gets disabled randomly and refuses to become enabled

Tags: bluetooth

I'm using various distros (including Ubuntu) on my laptop and in all of them, bluetooth disconnects randomly while watching videos or listening to music and refuses to get re-enabled. If I log out and log back in, the option to enable bluetooth just diappears

result for

`sudo dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'; uname -r; mokutil --sb`

```
[    2.849630] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware amdgpu/renoir_asd.bin
[    2.849651] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware amdgpu/renoir_ta.bin
[    2.849851] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware amdgpu/renoir_dmcub.bin
[    2.849853] [drm] Loading DMUB firmware via PSP: version=0x01010026
[    2.849882] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware amdgpu/renoir_pfp.bin
[    2.849897] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware amdgpu/renoir_me.bin
[    2.849909] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware amdgpu/renoir_ce.bin
[    2.849928] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware amdgpu/renoir_rlc.bin
[    2.850000] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware amdgpu/renoir_mec.bin
[    2.850646] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware amdgpu/renoir_vcn.bin
[    2.850647] [drm] Found VCN firmware Version ENC: 1.19 DEC: 5 VEP: 0 Revision: 0
[    2.850653] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: Will use PSP to load VCN firmware
[    3.068710] usb 1-4: Product: Bluetooth Radio 
[    5.220056] platform regulatory.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware regulatory.db
[    5.220242] platform regulatory.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware regulatory.db.p7s
[    5.365066] rtw_8821ce 0000:01:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware rtw88/rtw8821c_fw.bin
[    5.365078] rtw_8821ce 0000:01:00.0: Firmware version 24.11.0, H2C version 12
[    6.233122] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    6.233179] NET: Registered PF_BLUETOOTH protocol family
[    6.233181] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    6.233187] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    6.233191] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    6.233196] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    6.430314] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    6.430329] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    6.430348] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[    6.571781] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: examining hci_ver=08 hci_rev=000c lmp_ver=08 lmp_subver=8821
[    6.573686] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: rom_version status=0 version=1
[    6.573692] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: loading rtl_bt/rtl8821c_fw.bin
[    6.574137] bluetooth hci0: firmware: direct-loading firmware rtl_bt/rtl8821c_fw.bin
[    6.574160] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: loading rtl_bt/rtl8821c_config.bin
[    6.574229] bluetooth hci0: firmware: direct-loading firmware rtl_bt/rtl8821c_config.bin
[    6.574256] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: cfg_sz 10, total sz 34926
[    7.175716] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: fw version 0x75b8f098
[    7.266980] Bluetooth: MGMT ver 1.22
[    7.292190] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[    7.292200] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[    7.292206] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[ 2652.700829] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected event for opcode 0xfc19
[ 7125.098417] Bluetooth: hci0: HCI reset during shutdown failed
[ 7125.890408] Bluetooth: hci0: Opcode 0x c03 failed: -71
[ 7125.891430] Bluetooth: hci0: Opcode 0x c03 failed: -71
[ 7127.794429] Bluetooth: hci0: Opcode 0x c03 failed: -71
[ 7128.154419] Bluetooth: hci0: Opcode 0x c03 failed: -71
[ 7128.338440] Bluetooth: hci0: Opcode 0x c03 failed: -71
[ 7128.498423] Bluetooth: hci0: Opcode 0x c03 failed: -71
[ 7130.018445] Bluetooth: hci0: Opcode 0x c03 failed: -71
[ 7139.356775] Bluetooth: hci0: Opcode 0x c03 failed: -110
[ 7146.877262] Bluetooth: hci0: Opcode 0x c03 failed: -110
[ 7151.868985] Bluetooth: hci0: Opcode 0x c03 failed: -110
[ 7153.884794] Bluetooth: hci0: Opcode 0x c03 failed: -110
[ 7160.540773] Bluetooth: hci0: Opcode 0x c03 failed: -110
[ 7214.972773] Bluetooth: hci0: Opcode 0x c03 failed: -110
[ 7347.552773] Bluetooth: hci0: Opcode 0x c03 failed: -110
[ 7444.029021] Bluetooth: hci0: Opcode 0x c03 failed: -110
[ 7658.236759] Bluetooth: hci0: Opcode 0x c03 failed: -110
[ 7670.140796] Bluetooth: hci0: Opcode 0x c03 failed: -110
[ 7674.780771] Bluetooth: hci0: Opcode 0x c03 failed: -110
[ 8002.748802] Bluetooth: hci0: Opcode 0x c03 failed: -110
[ 8004.829015] Bluetooth: hci0: Opcode 0x c03 failed: -110
[ 8250.396894] Bluetooth: hci0: Opcode 0x c03 failed: -110
[ 8252.828781] Bluetooth: hci0: Opcode 0x c03 failed: -110
[ 8338.268757] Bluetooth: hci0: Opcode 0x c03 failed: -110
[ 8342.396796] Bluetooth: hci0: Opcode 0x c03 failed: -110
6.1.0-9-amd64
SecureBoot disabled
```

please give me a solution for this

I was reading through similar problems in this forum including that of Wi-Fi since a few hours.

it got fixed as of now. my wireless adapter (RTL8821CE) had bluetooth capabilities. and installing this "https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw88" and rebooting fixed my Wi-Fi as well as Bluetooth connectivity problems. will be updating if this issue appears again.

thank you